# Moving along bezier curve is not giving correct bends

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to give a bend to an object along the Bezier curve. But, as I slide the object its leading face and the rings inside the object get dense and the object slide slows down leading to the accumulation of all the rings along the bending path so the desired direction and length of the bend are all reduced to a very small amount. See picture. I am unable to find out why this happens.

[image]

Comment: It is very hard to see what kind of object you are trying to bend in the provided screenshot. Could you provide different views or more explaination please, including the Edit mode view of your curve?

Comment: I modified a cube to turn it into a chisel kind of thing. I have a video but here is no way to upload it.